# How does Class::getMethod with an Object.class parameter work?

Tags: java, reflection, compare

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Method method = String.class.getMethod("compareTo", Object.class);
    System.out.println(method);
}
```

Prints `public int java.lang.String.compareTo(java.lang.Object)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    "Foo".compareTo(new Object());
}
```

Doesn't compile, because `The method compareTo(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`.

Why?

Comment: Because the compiler knows the generic type parameter of `Comparable` for `String` is `<String>`. Reflection does not know that because of type erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements [`Comparable<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), which defines method [`compareTo(T o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-).

Because of type-erasure, that method is actually `compareTo(Object o)` at runtime.

Regardless of that, `String` implements that method as `compareTo(String o)`.

Since that has a different signature, the Java compiler generates a "synthetic" "bridge" method to make it work, which means you end up with:

```java
public interface Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Object o);
}

public class String implements Comparable {
    public int compareTo(String o) {
        ...
    }
    public synthetic bridge int compareTo(Object o) {
        return compareTo((String) o);
    }
}
```

`synthetic` and `bridge` are of course not actual keywords you can put in a Java source file, but those modifiers are present in the reflection data at runtime.

*Synthetic* methods are generated by the compiler for internal reasons, so they are considered "hidden", which means you cannot see them in a Java source file, and that is why `compareTo(new Object())`  will not compile.

You can however see the method through reflection, but as you can see from the implementation shown here, if you actually called `compareTo(new Object())` through reflection, you'd get a [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is *exactly* the issue that generics work to fix. At compile time, the compiler can use generics to tell you that comparing a String to an Object will not work.

At runtime however, generics are erased. So you can compare a String to an Object, as per the Object method parameters.

Comment: You can't actually compare them; you'd get a class cast exception if you use an object other than a string. But the method signature doesn't tell you that (without generics).

Comment: @khelwood true. Which is why you should/need to read the docs, which state exactly this

Comment: @ControlAltDel Why are there two method instances at runtime (compareTo(Object) and compareTo(String)? Generics are erased sounds like there would be only compareTo(Object).

Comment: @user3561614 I don't know what a method instance is, but there is only one method. The difference is only that generics help to identify this problem at compile time, rather than letting the user run into it at runtime. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: @ControlAltDel `String.class.getMethod("compareTo", String.class)` returns a Method instance. Generics are erased explains the instance returned from `String.class.getMethod("compareTo", Object.class)`, but why also the instance with String.class parameter?

Comment: There is no "instance" with String.class. Again, this is strictly extended compile time checking to make sure you call compareTo correctly